# Add Unordered List of items in database?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, html-lists

I'm trying to build a table of string content that has several columns, some including a (bulleted) unordered list. Is this considered a value list, an array, or something else? This is an example:

````
|----|----------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1 | Transition Age Youth | • Wrap-around services • Case management • Voluntary residential services • Employment and permanent housing support | • Outreach and engagement  • Telemedicine  • Counseling and services |```

Is this as simple as using line breaks /n or /r/n in the data itself? 

I'll be using this as an open-data directory of services. I intend to have a search function where people can find all records containing keywords they specify. There's about 10 more columns I'm not showing which would help others narrow by filtering rows. 

Thank you for any insight. 

[!This photo illustrates one of several tables. Some have multiple unordered lists, this one illustrates a single list. There may be a limited list of options if that would help knowing too.[1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaTmV.png
````

Comment: Before you think about exactly how to store the list, you should be ready to explain all the ways you'll be dealing with it.  Are you going to be dynamically adding elements to the list?  Does each list item relate to other data such as  Are you going to be performing text based search?  Tim's "normalize list items into a table" approach is textbook but it's really only appropriate if each list item is related to data.  These might be more like tags, or even arbitrary content?

Answer (score 1):

Bullet-separated (or any text delimiter separated) values generally represent unnormalized data, and you should avoid storing this in your database.  I suggest the following design:

```
id | idx | desc
1  | 1   | Prevent re-institutionalization and homelessness;
1  | 2   | Transition Age Youth
1  | 3   | Wrap-around services
1  | 4   | Case management
1  | 5   | Voluntary residential services
```

If you want to generate a bullet-separated list, just use Postgres' `string_agg` function:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    string_agg(desc, '•' order by idx) as list
FROM your_table
GROUP BY
    id;
```

Comment: need an index between `your_table` and the descriptions table; OP example preserves this relationship

Comment: Thank you for this Tim. My challenge is having several columns with unordered lists for each record. Can I use the same table you suggested and add a column that would hold the table's column name?

Comment: is there a constraint on `list.id == desc.id` there I'm missing? I'm also noticing this creates a bullet _separated_ list, not quite the same as a "bulleted list" in which every list element is _preceeded_ by the bullet.  Interestingly enough you've solved the harder of the two problems

Comment: Not sure now what you are asking for.  Please edit your question and show us.

Comment: Never put a column name in a table row.  It's a sure sign that you need to denormalize your data.  Columns are appropriate when there is a specific and universal relationship between the data.  But what relationship _does_ exist between the list elements and their parent item?  Do all items have the same set lists?  Or is there a more dynamic relationship there?